# MYSQL INNER JOIN between 5 databases

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I repeat myself several times this frequently asked question, but I think it is suitable for a better direction to the problem. I work in the PHPMYADMIN environment. My goal was to download data from the internet that describes the judges, the regions in which they work, the files they made, the number of decisions, their salaries and similar things that I upload to my databases. I created 5 databases, each of which symbolizes a specific region (part of the country). Now my goal is, for example, to find the judge with the highest number of decisions or the average salary of a judge or judges, and things like that. The following display lists the judge as judge_id and his number of decisions (from all five databases)

```
select id_sudca, rozhodnutia 
from sudy_sk.informacie 
INNER JOIN  sudcovia on informacie.ID_sudca = sudcovia.ID_sudca
union all 
select id_sudcu, rozhodnutie 
from nabozny1.sudca 
INNER JOIN sudca on m_priznania.id_sudcu = sudca.id_sudcu
union all 
select sudca_id, pocet_rozhodnuti 
from `kosice`.sudca 
INNER JOIN sudca on sudca.SUDCA_ID =  sudca.SUDCA_ID
union all 
select id_sudca, rozhodnutia 
from gerboc.sudcovia 
INNER JOIN sudcovia on sudcovia.ID_sudca = sudcovia.ID_sudca
union all 
select id_sudcu, rozhodnutia 
from biz.sudcovia 
INNER JOIN sudcovia on sudcovia.ID_SUDCU = sudcovia.ID_SUDCU
order by rozhodnutia desc;
```

So I get an output from this display and when I want to click on judge_id (find out who is hiding under this ID) it does not throw me into the judges' home table (because I entered inner join, lenze I can't come up with the correct syntax how to connect it there) one database has a table of judges with the primary boy judge_id, which refers to foreign boys, and another has a shelf called NAME, SURNAME and other things, and the other database has NAME and Surname put in the pile, I also tried the display concat but the inner join came to me more suitable.

Comment: Looks like the source code repository for rclone is on github: https://github.com/rclone/rclone . Is this not enough?

Comment: I would need more information about encrypting the header

Comment: The image is not visible in your question.